# How do you use geometry nodes to set position with vertex group?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I use a vertex group to set the end position of a bezier segment?

[image]

Comment: make a vertex group then you a named attribute node to access it for use as the selection.

Comment: The named attribute node doesn't loop through the indexes so it outputs a default value of 0 or 1

Comment: Do you think this could work with a vertex group? If I box-select a few vertices and assign them to a vertex group in which order would you get them from the group? What defines the order? Is there an order at all?

Comment: If you want to convert edges to a curve, you may want to use Mesh to Curve with an empty curve input

Comment: I see what you are saying, and a vertex group can't work. do you want to set the vertex index manually?